# Fake GPS location on Windows 10 hosted network

Tags: geolocation, gps, virtual-wifi, network-location, wireless-hotspot

I recently made a hosted network in my Windows 10 following these steps: [link](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-turn-your-windows-10-pc-wireless-hotspot)

So I was wondering if there is a way I can fake my gps location and change it to whatever point in the map I want. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot fake GPS location with a WiFi network. Your hotspot has actually nothing to do with GPS.

GPS is a positioning system which calculates the location of a receiver relative to satellites. See [GPS Fundamentals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Fundamentals).

[GPS Spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoofing_attack#GPS_Spoofing) is a mechanism which alters (usually by delaying or repeating) the signals between the satellites and the receiver.

These mechanisms are separate from tower triangulation-based location or positioning systems based on proximity to WiFi network signals.

Comment: So it's not possible that my smartphone can get false location position from my Pc's hotspot? (I have assigned on my smartphone that it takes location data from wifi)

Comment: First, it's not GPS location. Second, if you are in reach of cellular network, your location would be primarily based on cell tower triangulation. Third, if you are within reach of other WiFi networks, their location would also count. If you isolate your device from other signals and the application would calculate the location based on a signal from one source and it matched its location database, you might end up with a device being assigned to a different location. With a Windows-based hotspot likely a pure chance.